# Indentation Error in python code

Tags: python, indentation

```
def get_top_grossing_movie_list(url):
movies_list = []
r = requests.get(url)
for each_url in BeautifulSoup(r.text).select('.title a[href*="title"]'):
    movie_title = each_url.text 
    if movie_title != 'X':
        movies_list.append((movie_title, each_url['href']))
return movies_list
```

In line 4, I am getting:

> Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

But I feel my indentations are correct. Please give ways to solve it out.

Comment: Which IDE/Editor are you using ? I would suggest Sublime Text or VIM to avoid these silly mistakes in future.

Comment: I am using Sublime Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second line after the `def get_top_grossing_movie_list(url):` must be indented and all the rest of the code accordingly:

```
def get_top_grossing_movie_list(url):
    movies_list = []
    r = requests.get(url)
    for each_url in BeautifulSoup(r.text).select('.title a[href*="title"]'):
        movie_title = each_url.text 
        if movie_title != 'X':
            movies_list.append((movie_title, each_url['href']))
    return movies_list
```

Comment: great I am glad that helped! you might want to mark my answer as the right answer.

Comment: @user3654181, If you find the answer is working for you, then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use spacebar 4 times rather than tab to indent. The reason you might be getting this error is because tab might not be equal to 4 spaces.

Comment: Or, *much easier*, just tell your IDE that tab means four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

When happening `Indentation Error`, it has as below:

1. Mix tab and space
2. Invoke `def` or `class` in first line after it need to add Indentation

You problem belongs first statement so you code have to be as below:

```
def get_top_grossing_movie_list(url):
    movies_list = []
    r = requests.get(url)
    for each_url in BeautifulSoup(r.text).select('.title a[href*="title"]'):
        movie_title = each_url.text 
        if movie_title != 'X':
            movies_list.append((movie_title, each_url['href']))
    return movies_list
```